# vb6 - NUMERIC and microsoft ole db provider for sql server

Tags: sql-server, vb6, numeric

First of all sorry for the bad english.

I want to make the following query: "select top 1 NumeroLote from tblLote where convert(numeric(12), Documento)=28405"

The data for "Documento" is stored on a varchar field and sometimes is recorded as "002008" or "2008"... That's  why I was trying to use numeric.

It works on sql server 2008 but when I use it from vb6 using Provider="sqloledb"and Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.0 library, I get the following error: "numeric is not a recognized function name. Microsoft Ole Db provider for sql server".

Do you know some alternatives, I can only think of using "like".

EDIT: Documento might be varchar(12)

Answer: bigint

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Try `CONVERT(DECIMAL(12, 0), DocumentNo) = ...`

Comment: Got the same message decimal is not a recognized function name. :(

Comment: This all begs the question of "why isn;t the database column typed correctly?"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The data for "Documento" is stored on a varchar field and sometimes is recorded as "002008" or "2008"... That's why I was trying to use numeric.

Is the number always an integer? If so, try using this instead:

```
CONVERT(INT, Documento)
```

**Edit**: Use bigint to avoid the overflow problem:

```
CONVERT(BIGINT, Documento)
```

Comment: Its varchar(12) so it won't work with integer. I've updated the question. :(

Comment: How do you mean, it won't work? Because the values won't match? Or an integer isn't big enough?

Comment: Integer isn't big enough: the conversion of the varchar value '03400110858' overflowed an int column, maximum integer value exceeded. Its close because INT exists...